# Angular RXJS, finish observable before return

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

i want to know how to 'wait' without using async/await to finish observable and then return that value

```
// import {Observable, of} from 'rxjs';
getFirstQueue() {
  if (this.insideVar) {
    return of(this.insideVar);
  }
  this.http.get(this.createUrl(`some_resource`)).subscribe((someVar: any) => {
    this.insideVar = someVar;
  });
  return this.insideVar;
}
```

Comment: You want an synchronus function that returns asynchronus a value? That seems to be not use-full from the outer world perspective. You can return an observable via your function. The caller knows now its asynchronus and either uses it as an observable or subscribes to it and emits an sideeffect, or pushes the value into a variable.

Comment: "I would like you to go ask Aaron when his vacation is, but I'd like you to give me the answer right here right now already". Essentially this is what you're asking when you want to synchronously return something that can only be fetched asynchronously. It just doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, on return it should be `of(this.insideVar) `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't return from a subscription. You have to return an `Observable`. A function higher up the stack will then subscribe to this observable.

You can use `tap` to perform the same side-effect you are currently doing in the subscribe body before returning.

```js
getFirstQueue(): Observable<any> {
  if (this.activeQueue) {
    return of(this.activeQueue);
  }
  return this.http.get(this.createUrl(`some_resource`)).pipe(
    tap((someVar: any) => {
      this.insideVar = someVar;
    })
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to go from asynchronous callback to synchronous context. For that you need to use `async/await`, but if you take a look at the decompiled code the `async/await` is just a syntactic sugar on top of Promises, so it only looks like it came from async to sync